# Clean way of receiving image_dimensions after applying image_style

Tags: files, media

I'm quite a Drupal-Newbie and am wondering what would be the best way to receive the dimensions of an image after applying some styles.

I have the URI of the image before the style and absolute URL after applying the style with `image_style_url`

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, which does not look neat, but works:

`$sizes = getimagesize(drupal_realpath(image_style_path('style', $imageURI)));`